# How do I extract a value in [[ ]] in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

In some JSON I am working with, it has the following:

```
"value": [["field1", "field2"]]
```

I need to be able to pull out `field1` and `field2`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it doing it:

```
var test = { "value": [ [ "field1", "field2" ] ] };
           ^          ^ ^    ^         ^
           |          | |    |         |
          [1]        [2|3]  [4]       [5]

// [1] test is an object
// [2] test.value is an array of array
// [3] test.value[0] is an array("field1", "field2")
// [4] test.value[0][0] is "field1"
// [5] test.value[0][1] is "field2"
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just an array within an array, so you access the data with indices:

```
data.value[0][0] == 'field1'
data.value[0][1] == 'field2'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
field1 = value[0][0]
field2 = value[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already parsed it:

```
var o = {"value": [["field1", "field2"]]};
console.log(o.value[0][0], o.value[0][1]);
```